# Flash:AS3 - pause for x Seconds?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I make a code to pause the video for a certain time and then continue on after?  (or play a specified frame)

Comment: Are you using flex or flash for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// mc is a class movie clip

private function pause():void {
    this.mc.gotoAndStop(4);   // stop mc at frame 4
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);    // fire after 5 sec
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    timer.start(); 
}

private function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    this.mc.gotoAndPlay(10);   // play from 10th frame
}
```

Note: I have not compiled the code, but guess that you have got the idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, I kind of forgot to mention that I am very new to flash.
I do know the very basics but nothing too complex, such as something like that.  Could you explain that code a little bit?

Comment: Opps. You want to pause a movie clip at a specific frame, right? gotoAndStop(n) stops playing the movie clip and frame 4. Then you configure a timer to fire after specific (5 sec in the example) time. When the timer fires you start your movie clip again from frame m by calling gotoAndPlay(m). That's all. You may Google for how to work with timer in AS3.

Comment: what is a class movie clip and why cant I use the private function on a regular movie?

Comment: class movie clip means mc is a member variable of the class and mc is an instance of MovieClip. These are OOP things. If you don't know what class variable or private means then you should start from more basic things. Please be more specific in the question (what you tried, where you stuck etc.). Otherwise it's difficult to answer rightly.

Answer (score 1):

I see this tread is old, but for you guys who find this later on I found this simple script

Write this script in that certain frame you want to pause your animation.

```
stop();
setTimeout(play, Math.random() * 3500); // 3500 = 3,5 sec
```

Another one I found which also works

```
// Call the function, time in seconds
sleep(5);
  function sleep(sec){
// Stops the script on the current frame
   stop();
// The actual pause, and starter
setTimeout(this.gotoAndPlay, sec*1000, this.currentFrame + 1);
}
```